# How to use Modi without installing 2003 office web

Tags: vb.net, dll, modi

I use modi to do OCR.

Then I want to install the same program on my webserver. Obviously you can't install microsoft 2003 on hostgator hosting.

The problem is, of course, the program need to refer to modi.dll.

I saw several files here:

Interop.MODI.dll (what is this file anyway a wrapper)?
MDIVWCTL.DLL this seems to be the real .dll

In my program if I tried to add reference to mdivwctl.dll I got this error:
A reference to 'D:\business\shared\dropbox\Dropbox\badgers\dotNet\Thumbnailer\WebApplication1\MDIVWCTL.DLL' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

My programmer can add that but only in his computer.

Basically I want the dll to function by itself without registering, etc.

How to achieve that? How do I upload the program to windows shared hosting using asp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Desktop based application that is using MODI for OCR. At the time of writing the application, 4 months ago, I did some good amount of research into this area. I gave up after a while and just installed the free Sharepoint 2007 which includes `MDIVWCTL.DLL`. It does not seem likely that you can surpass the requirements of the assembly, it might have references to other components.

Comment: even if mdivwctl.dll requires other file, why can't I just use those other files?

Comment: Because, even if you could, that would be illegal

Comment: Could I? I don't mind buying a whole 2003 office. The issue is I need to run it on the web.

Comment: Have you tried other solutions in the area like Tesseract? Also, take a look at Adobe Acrobat Pro and see if you can automate that. Working with various dlls and their dependancies is definitely painfull, because some of them may even be installed in the GAC. Working back with a professional program to recompile may be very very hard.

Comment: What is GAC? What do you mean? I can just use windows server. I can't use shared hosting. That's the only thing that sucks.

Comment: To rehash, MDIVWCTL.DLL is the core DLL that you need for using MODI. That being said, you CANNOT just reference this assembly in your project and expect it to work. You can and should only reference the libraries that are meant to be referenced. This dll is something that comes with other microsoft programs like Office 2003 and Sharepoint 2007. It will have references to other components and  it is very unlikely that you can somehow reverse engineer this process and use the dll.